# The Item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found, while download app from google play

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play

Don't know but i have not included any permission or any feature of in-app billing, I have just put normal application on play store, but when i want to download it from play store, it saying me that "**The Item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found,**

### [image: Heading]

Comment: The same happened to me today, when I first published a new app at Google Play. Could that be a problem from Google Play? By the way, the app is free.

Comment: The same also happened to me today. I think it is a problem from Google Play. Question is if it is going to work by itself?

Comment: I hope so. Are your apps free too? Do they have anything to do with In-App billing? Most comments I read about this issue are related with apps with In-App billing

Comment: My app is also free, and dosen't have any In-App billing. So it is very strange. I consider trying publich the app again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here is what happened. I'll explain it so if someone has this exact problem might not be as worried as I was.

- I published a fresh new App at 9.00 morning
- The app was free and it didn't have any In-app billing
- An hour later or so, the app appeared as available but it couldn't be downloaded. The error was allways as described above: "The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found."
- From the Google Play website console, the app also seemed available, but the message was: "This app is incompatible with all your devices".

There had to be some bad sinchronization among the Google Play servers, because after some hours, at about 17:00h afternoon, the problem was solved. And I didn't need to do anything. So, be patient!!

Comment: Thanks @jsidera i also get same situation